# laravel role based spatie package unable to install

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am using php 7.0.33 version and laravel 5.5, I want to download the spatie package, but its not installing. I am getting an error with php 7.0.33 not supported. I tried to install with 7.0.33 package but unable to install.

Can anyone give me a suggestion on how to install it php 7.0 version?
I don't want to update my php version.

```
composer require "spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^7.0.0"

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
composer require spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^6.0.0
```

This library version must be correct for your php's version and Laravel.